# IBM Worklight - Frequently switch the skins after Application started-up

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-skins

My observation is that a Worklight application invokes skinLoader.js->getSkinName one time if the application is just installed or updated with skin changed. Is it correct?

Is there a way to switch the skins on-the-fly after the Worklight application has started up?

Comment: Is this question resolved? please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot switch Worklight Skins during runtime as the feature design does not allow for this.